# Failed to construct transformer: Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported

Tags: react-native

``
Failed to construct transformer:  Error: error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
at new Hash (node:internal/crypto/hash:67:19)
at Object.createHash (node:crypto:133:10)
at stableHash (E:\Project\consumer-app\node_modules\metro-cache\src\stableHash.js:19:8)
at Object.getCacheKey (E:\Project\consumer-app\node_modules\metro-transform-worker\src\index.js:593:7)
at getTransformCacheKey (E:\Project\consumer-app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\getTransformCacheKey.js:24:19)
at new Transformer (E:\Project\consumer-app\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Transformer.js:48:9)
at E:\Project\consumer-app\node_modules\metro\src\Bundler.js:22:29
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
opensslErrorStack: [ 'error:03000086:digital envelope routines::initialization error' ],
library: 'digital envelope routines',
reason: 'unsupported',
code: 'ERR_OSSL_EVP_UNSUPPORTED'
}

[image: app error screen]

downgraded node version to 14

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.